# how to update columns with empty value

Tags: php, mysql

Im using mysql, when I want to update a column with this query

```
UPDATE books 
   SET ISBN = $ISBN
     , Title = '$BookTitle'
     , PublicationDate = '$PublicationDate'
     , Publisher = '$Publisher'
     , Edition = $Edition
     , Volume = $Volume
     , books.Author_AuthorId = $AuthorId 
 WHERE ISBN = $GETISBN;
```

with php it works well while all the input are filled in HTML FORM but if one input is empty already or I clear the previous data in HTML Form and Submit the Form it issues this error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`Volume`=1, `books`.`Author_AuthorId`=3 WHERE `ISBN`=5456165156' at line 2

What Should I do?

Comment: Most likely `$Volume` contains a single quote or something that breaks the query. Have you considered preparing and executing this?

Comment: Possibly because `$Edition` is a string value and is missing its single quotes.

Comment: Also `$ISBN` is likely not strictly numeric and therefore also requires quotes. You'll find that they include hyphens, which MySQL misinterprets as a subtraction expression (also they often end with `X`)

Comment: May be due to ending backtick $GETISBN`

Comment: Echo your query u will get the idea

Comment: You should prepare your data. Check for empty values and replace them with some default value.

Comment: But As I Wrote The Query In my Question None Of Numeric fields like Volume , Edition, ISBN has quote, and also I Considered the ISBN only numeric I mean without the hyphen

Comment: Good Idea @devpro I found the problem

Comment: Nice to read this what is the error? After echo? U get?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the query which I have echoed

```
UPDATE `books` SET `ISBN`=5456165156,`Title`='500 Notice About Java',`PublicationDate`='1390-05-25', `Publisher`='Qods Publication',`Edition`=,`Volume`=1, `books`.`Author_AuthorId`=3 WHERE `ISBN`=5456165156
```

As long as The $Edition is empty Then The Query Changes like this

```
`Edition`=
```

Thats why Mysql can not Understand what value should be set to Edition

Comment: Lol... That way I suggest to echo your query

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It shows the cause of the error, but doesn't explain how to fix it.

Comment: If `$Edition` is single-quoted, you won't get this error in this circumstance, but using a prepared statement would avoid the problem entirely. And yes, you must quote the ISBN because the check digit is `X` 10% of the time. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_digit#ISBN_10

Comment: Here is what we have to do
    $Edition = $_POST['Edition'];
       if (empty($Edition) ){
           $Edition="NULL";
       }
       $Volume = $_POST['Volume'];
       if (empty($Volume) ){
           $Volume="NULL";
       }
Those Fields which are numeric, should be initialized with NULL Value if they are left blank